# SegFault when using pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads

I am trying to work on a project for my OS class, and I am getting a SegFault while working with pthreads, but I am not really sure what is causing the problem.

As for the program, I am trying to accomplish the following program :

> There is a deep canyon somewhere in Kruger National Park, South Africa, and a single rope that spans the canyon. 
>   Baboons can cross the canyon by swinging hand- over-hand on the rope, but if two baboons going in opposite directions meet in the middle, they will fight and drop to their deaths. Furthermore, the rope is only strong enough to hold three baboons. If there are more baboons on the rope at the same time, it will break. Assuming that we can teach the baboons to use semaphores, we would like to design a synchronization scheme with the following properties.
>
> 1. Once a baboon has begun to cross, it is guaranteed to get to the other side without running into a baboon going the other way.
> 2. There are never more than three baboons on the rope. The order of the baboons crossing the rope should be preserved; i.e., the order in which they enter the rope should be the order in which they exit the rope.
> 3. A continuing stream of baboons crossing in one direction should not bar baboons going the other way indefinitely (no starvation). Solve this requirement such that the FIFO order is preserved. That is, a baboon trying to cross to the left/right that arrives earlier than a baboon trying to cross in the opposite direction gets on the rope first.

Basically, I am reading in a text file, and then simulating a FIFO system where some monkeys are trying to cross a rope bridge.
What is weird is that I was able to get the program to run a few times, but it would frequently cause a SegFault.

```
pthread_create(&eastern[i],NULL,(void *) &east_side,(void *)&id[i]);
pthread_create(&western[i],NULL,(void *) &west_side,(void *)&id[i]);
```

where east_side and west_side are below.

```
void* east_side(void*arg)            
{
    int baboon = *(int*)arg;
    int on_rope;
    sem_wait(&deadlock_protection);
    sem_wait(&east_mutex);
    east++;
    if (east == 1)
    {
        sem_wait(&rope);
        printf("Baboon %d: waiting\n", baboon);
    }
    sem_post(&east_mutex);
    sem_post(&deadlock_protection);
    sem_wait(&counter);
    sem_getvalue(&counter, &on_rope);
    printf("Baboon %d: Cross rope request granted (Current crossing: left to right, Number of baboons on rope: %d)\n", baboon,3-on_rope);
    sleep(travel_time);
    sem_getvalue(&counter, &on_rope);
    printf("Baboon %d: Exit rope (Current crossing: left to right, Number of baboons on rope: %d)\n", baboon, 2-on_rope);
    sem_post(&counter);
    sem_wait(&east_mutex);
    east--;
    if (east == 0)
        sem_post(&rope);
    sem_post(&east_mutex);
}

//thread handling west to east travel
void* west_side(void*arg)    
{
    int baboon = *(int*)arg;
    int on_rope;
    sem_wait(&deadlock_protection);
    sem_wait(&west_mutex);
    west++;
    if (west == 1)
    {
        sem_wait(&rope);
        printf("Baboon %d: waiting\n", baboon);
    }
    sem_post(&west_mutex);
    sem_post(&deadlock_protection);
    sem_wait(&counter);
    sem_getvalue(&counter, &on_rope);
    printf("Baboon %d: Cross rope request granted (Current crossing: right to left, Number of baboons on rope: %d)\n", baboon, 3-on_rope);
    sleep(travel_time);
    sem_getvalue(&counter, &on_rope);
    printf("Baboon %d: Exit rope (Current crossing: right to left, Number of baboons on rope: %d)\n", baboon, 2-on_rope);
    sem_post(&counter);
    sem_wait(&west_mutex);
    west--;
    if (west == 0)
        sem_post(&rope);
    sem_post(&west_mutex);

}
```

I am using a sample input in a plain text file of

```
L,R,R,R,R,R,L,L,R
```

This creates the output:

sh-4.3$ main input.txt 5
The input is
L R R R R R L L R
Baboon 1: Request to cross rope (left to right)
Baboon 1: waiting
Baboon 1: Cross rope request granted (Current crossing: left to right, Number of baboons on rope: 1)
Baboon 2: Request to cross rope (right to left)
Baboon 3: Request to cross rope (right to left)
Baboon 4: Request to cross rope (right to left)
Baboon 5: Request to cross rope (right to left)
Baboon 1: Exit rope (Current crossing: left to right, Number of baboons on rope: 0)
Baboon 2: waiting
Baboon 2: Cross rope request granted (Current crossing: right to left, Number of baboons on rope: 1)
Baboon 3: Cross rope request granted (Current crossing: right to left, Number of baboons on rope: 2)
Baboon 4: Cross rope request granted (Current crossing: right to left, Number of baboons on rope: 3)
Baboon 6: Request to cross rope (right to left)
Baboon 7: Request to cross rope (left to right)
Baboon 8: Request to cross rope (left to right)
Baboon 9: Request to cross rope (right to left)
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

I have included the entire file in case the problem is actually not where I think the problem is.

```
/*include header files*/

#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ipc.h>
#include <sys/shm.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
//#include <stdbool.h>


//compile with command 
//gcc -o main *.c -lpthread -lrt

/*semaphores*/
sem_t rope;
sem_t east_mutex;
sem_t west_mutex;
sem_t deadlock_protection;
sem_t counter;

/*global variables*/
int east = 0;
int west = 0;
int travel_time;    

/*function prototypes*/
void crossing(int x);
void* east_side(void*);
void* west_side(void*);

/*main function*/
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{ 

    char c;
    int baboonCnt=0;
    char temp[100];

    sem_init(&rope,0,1);                        //ensure mutual exclusion on rope ownership
    sem_init(&east_mutex,0,1);                  //east side on travel
    sem_init(&west_mutex,0,1);                  //west side on travel
    sem_init(&deadlock_protection,0,1);         //used to prevent deadlocks while using semaphores
    sem_init(&counter,0,3);                     //ensure only 3 baboons are allowed on the rope

    //ensure all input arguements are entered
    if ( argc == 3 )                    
    {
        travel_time = atoi(argv[2]);
        FILE *file;
        int baboonCnt=0;
        if (file = fopen(argv[1], "r") )
        {
            while((c=getc(file))!=EOF)
            {
                if(c == 'L'|| c == 'R')
                {
                    temp[baboonCnt] = c;
                    baboonCnt++;
                }
            }
        }
        else   
        {
            printf("Unable to read data from the input file.");
            return 0;
        }
        printf("The input is\n");
        int j=0;
        for(j;j<baboonCnt;++j)
        {
            printf("%c ",temp[j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
        int id[baboonCnt];
        pthread_t eastern[baboonCnt],western[baboonCnt];
        int i=0;
        for(i;i<baboonCnt;++i)
        {
            sleep(1);
            if(temp[i]=='L')
            {
                id[i] = i+1;
                printf("Baboon %d: Request to cross rope (left to right)\n", i+1);
                pthread_create(&eastern[i],NULL,(void *) &east_side,(void *)&id[i]);
            }
            else if(temp[i]=='R')
            {
                id[i] = i+1;
                printf("Baboon %d: Request to cross rope (right to left)\n", i+1);
                pthread_create(&western[i],NULL,(void *) &west_side,(void *)&id[i]);
            }
        }
        int k=0;
        printf("before k loop");
        for(k;k<baboonCnt;++k)
        {

            pthread_join(eastern[k],NULL);
            printf("eastern",k);
            pthread_join(western[k],NULL); 
            printf("western %d",k);         
        }

        //destroy all semaphores
        sem_destroy (&rope); 
        sem_destroy (&east_mutex);
        sem_destroy (&west_mutex);
        sem_destroy (&deadlock_protection);
        sem_destroy (&counter);
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Proper command line usage is: \n<name> <filename> <cross time>\n");
    }
}
//thread handling the east to west to travel
void* east_side(void*arg)            
{
    int baboon = *(int*)arg;
    int on_rope;
    sem_wait(&deadlock_protection);
    sem_wait(&east_mutex);
    east++;
    if (east == 1)
    {
        sem_wait(&rope);
        printf("Baboon %d: waiting\n", baboon);
    }
    sem_post(&east_mutex);
    sem_post(&deadlock_protection);
    sem_wait(&counter);
    sem_getvalue(&counter, &on_rope);
    printf("Baboon %d: Cross rope request granted (Current crossing: left to right, Number of baboons on rope: %d)\n", baboon,3-on_rope);
    sleep(travel_time);
    sem_getvalue(&counter, &on_rope);
    printf("Baboon %d: Exit rope (Current crossing: left to right, Number of baboons on rope: %d)\n", baboon, 2-on_rope);
    sem_post(&counter);
    sem_wait(&east_mutex);
    east--;
    if (east == 0)
        sem_post(&rope);
    sem_post(&east_mutex);
}

//thread handling west to east travel
void* west_side(void*arg)    
{
    int baboon = *(int*)arg;
    int on_rope;
    sem_wait(&deadlock_protection);
    sem_wait(&west_mutex);
    west++;
    if (west == 1)
    {
        sem_wait(&rope);
        printf("Baboon %d: waiting\n", baboon);
    }
    sem_post(&west_mutex);
    sem_post(&deadlock_protection);
    sem_wait(&counter);
    sem_getvalue(&counter, &on_rope);
    printf("Baboon %d: Cross rope request granted (Current crossing: right to left, Number of baboons on rope: %d)\n", baboon, 3-on_rope);
    sleep(travel_time);
    sem_getvalue(&counter, &on_rope);
    printf("Baboon %d: Exit rope (Current crossing: right to left, Number of baboons on rope: %d)\n", baboon, 2-on_rope);
    sem_post(&counter);
    sem_wait(&west_mutex);
    west--;
    if (west == 0)
        sem_post(&rope);
    sem_post(&west_mutex);
}
```

Comment: When debugging segfaults, **gdb** (or similar debugger) is absolutely invaluable, and not that hard to learn - and lots of tutorials available: https://www.google.com/search?q=gdb+tutorial
Also - you'll probably get much better answers by posting a **minimal, complete and verifiable example** - more info here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: +1 for the advice on using a debugger - you'll learn much more in the long run if you do the hard yards yourself rather than turning to help for basic debugging. If you have exhausted your debugging avenues, as a minimum you should tell us exactly what the current behaviour of your program is - you have quite a few debug statements in your program (a good thing) so it would make sense to share exactly what the output is leading up to the crash. And we also need to know the exact input if we were to try and reproduce the problem.

Comment: One problem: The loop that makes the `pthead_create` calls does not populate every index of the `western` and `eastern` pid arrays. That is, those arrays have gaps where the pid values are garbage. Yet your `pthread_join` loop tries to use every index in those two arrays. That is, some of the `pthread_join` calls are being passed junk values.

Comment: @kaylum Alright, thanks for the advise. I edited the post some to reflect your suggestions. As for the pthread_create loop, I'll take a look at how I can change that and see if that helps.

Comment: @kaylum it appears that was the source of my problem. As soon as I implemented a fix to that problem, the segFault problem appeared to have gone away. I need to try continue testing it to be sure there is no problems, but at first glance, it seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others in this thread have mentioned, I encountered an error with my code where i was trying to access array elements that had not been initialized properly. I am summing up my changes in this post here. Most of the thanks go @kaylum for helping me reach this conclusion.

These array accesses occurred here:

```
for(k;k<baboonCnt;++k)
    {

        pthread_join(eastern[k],NULL);
        printf("eastern",k);
        pthread_join(western[k],NULL); 
        printf("western %d",k);         
    }
```

The improperly initializing occur in the lines

```
for(i;i<baboonCnt;++i)
    {
        sleep(1);
        if(temp[i]=='L')
        {
            id[i] = i+1;
            printf("Baboon %d: Request to cross rope (left to right)\n", i+1);
            pthread_create(&eastern[i],NULL,(void *) &east_side,(void *)&id[i]);
        }
        else if(temp[i]=='R')
        {
            id[i] = i+1;
            printf("Baboon %d: Request to cross rope (right to left)\n", i+1);
            pthread_create(&western[i],NULL,(void *) &west_side,(void *)&id[i]);
        }
    }
```

These two groups of code were what were causing the problems in execution, including the SegFault I was experiencing. 
Modifying the initialization section to instead create 2 separate arrays of ids, one referencing east baboons and the other referencing west baboons, rather than simply keeping all the ids in one group, was key to making the program work. After adjusting the id key storage method, the pthread_join loops also needed to be modified so that they properly accessed the arrays.

Here is the modified initialization section:

```
int eastcnt=0, westcnt=0, eastid[eastBab], westid[westBab], i=0;
    for(i;i<baboonCnt;++i)
      {
        sleep(1);
        if(temp[i]=='L')
          {
        eastid[eastcnt]=i;
        printf("Baboon %d wants to cross left to right\n",i);
        pthread_create(&eastern[eastcnt],NULL, (void *) &east_side,(void *) &eastid[eastcnt] );
        ++eastcnt;
          }
        else if(temp[i]=='R')
          {
        westid[westcnt]=i;
        printf("Baboon %d wants to cross right to left\n",i);
        pthread_create(&western[westcnt],NULL, (void *) &west_side,(void *) &westid[westcnt] );
        ++westcnt;
          }
      }
```

and the modified pthread_join loops

```
int k =0;
    for(k;k<westBab;++k)
    {
        pthread_join(western[k],NULL); 
    }
    k=0;
    for(k;k<eastBab;++k)
    {
        pthread_join(eastern[k],NULL); 
    }
```

After making the above changes, and some general cleaning up, the entire program works to specification.

Answer (score 0):

running valgrind is almost imediate to detect your error:

```
==10217== Use of uninitialised value of size 8
==10217==    at 0x4E39241: pthread_join (in /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.18.so)
==10217==    by 0x400E64: main (example.c:103)
```

line 103 is `pthread_join(eastern[k],NULL);`; valgrind stresses that the eastern array is read while not set.

Your arrays  are not fulfilled, you access elements that were not set.
You can probably modify the join loop in this manner:

```
for(k;k<baboonCnt;++k)
{
    if(temp[k]=='L') {
            pthread_join(eastern[k],NULL);
            printf("eastern %d\n",k);
    }
    else if(temp[k]=='R') {
            pthread_join(western[k],NULL);
            printf("western %d\n",k);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, in one of the comments from the original post, someone pointed this out. I have since made a change to it where I created separate arrays for both east and west baboons and used those to iterate through my pthread_join()'s. However, to do this I ended up running two separate loops. So i end up with one loop going through pthread_join(eastern) and one for pthread_join(western). I no longer have a SegFault problem, and it runs. Now, my current version has a problem where baboons are not crossing in the order they arrive.